# Non-zero bias parameter in scikit-learn decreases classification quality

Tags: scikit-learn, classification, svm, libsvm, tf-idf

I'm using [scikit-learn's LinearSVC](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html) as a statistical classifier in text classification. My features are uncentered [tf-idf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf).

When the `fit_intercept` attribute is set to `False`, classification accuracy increases significantly, which contradicts the expectation that the absolute values of features does not impact the performance of a statistical classifier.

What can cause the change in classification accuracy I am observing?

Comment: Are you in a multi-class or binary setting? Also, you are talking about generalization, i.e. test performance, right? The training performance definitely should be better with intercept.

Comment: I't a multilabel set (handled by OneVsRestClassifier). I'm talking about test performance of course.

Comment: Can you check the training performance?
The only explanation that comes to my mind is that there is an imbalance between label presents and absence in the training set, but not in the test-set.

Comment: The training performance is very good in both cases (with and without intercept). The imbalance is not likely to be the reason because the training and testing sets were obtained randomly from one bigger set.